# What is the best way to get 24 hours worth of a user's Twitter feed?

Tags: twitter

Using the Twitter API, what's the best way to collect 24 hours of a user's Twitter feed?  In other words I want to collect every tweet that showed up in my personal Twitter stream (those tweets posted by people I'm following) over the course of 24 hours.

Does the API allow you to get that many tweets? Is it possible to accomplish this without using the streaming (real-time) API?

Answer (score 1):

it is possible, and I have been doing it for some testing over the last few days. If you have a look at the [Streaming API Methods](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods) page on Twitter, there is a mention of the filter stream. Read up on the "follow" method, which takes a text file with the IDs of the users you want to watch (can also be gotten though [GET Friends](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids) and [GET Followers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids)). It will start streaming JSON back to you. Using CURL, you can stream direct to a file and then use that for later. I ran it last night on the sample stream and got back about 1.7Gb of Tweets in about 5 hours (but that's a 5% "sample" of tweets). I will be using this for testing...